# Future Subjunctive idioms/essay usage

Tags: gramática, modismos, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales, literatura

I am aware of the saying 'Donde fueres haz lo que vieres'. I wanted to know if there are any other idioms that use the future subjunctive and whether I could use the tense in a literature essay such as 'La casa de Bernarda Alba' or 'Como agua para chocolate'.

Comment: I mean, you can always use it (others on here know I'm keen to use with pretty high frequency), a literary essay is exactly where one might expect to see modern speakers actively using it.  Unfortunately, list questions are off topic on here.  The main phrase I can think of is "fuere/sea lo que sea" and several variants thereof (venga lo que viniere, etc).